# Customizing Allure report hierarchy for Cucumber.js tests with Playwright and TypeScript

Tags: allure, cucumberjs, playwright-typescript

I'm using Cucumber.js with Playwright and TypeScript for end-to-end testing of my application. I've integrated Allure for generating test reports. However, I'm struggling to customize the report hierarchy to accommodate scenarios that run for different brands and environments.

Currently, my tests are organized using tags like @test, and I execute them with environment variables $env:BRAND = "nextbet" and $env:ENV = "int" using the following command:

```
$env:BRAND = "brandname"; $env:ENV = "environemnt"; npx cucumber-js --tags '@test'
```

However, I want to customize the Allure report hierarchy to reflect the environment (ENV) as the EPIC and the brand (BRAND) as the feature, with the rest of the scenarios nested under them.

How can I achieve this customization in my Allure report generation setup for Cucumber.js tests with Playwright and TypeScript? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.